# Navigate to another view when the code enters the 'Success' or 'Failure' blocks

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

The following code is part from my Controller class;

1.) When the code enters the `Success` or `Failure` blocks, i need the program to navigate to another view, which will show the `Registration View` or `Information View`.

```
 Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url: 'http://call.com/the_webservice',
                        params : values,

                        failure: function (response) {
                        var text = response.responseText;
                         // SHOW SIGN UP SCREEN

                        },                              success: function (response) {
                        var text = response.responseText;
                         // GO TO ANOTHER VIEW AND IT WILL SHOW THE USER WITH SOME INFORMATION

                        }

                        });
```

**UPDATE**

In app.js

```
views: ['Main','HomePage','Register'],
```

and

```
launch: function() {

        // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
        Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

        // Initialize the main view
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('app.view.Main'));

                Ext.Viewport.add(app.view.Register);

    },
```

Then in the ControllerPage.js on button press...

```
success: function (response) {
                            var text = response.responseText;
                            var result = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                            Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(0);

                             console.log("success");

                            }
```

the console log, `success` gets printed, but the view doesn't navigate to the `Register` View

**UPDATE 2**

I have not used `tabPanel`, In my code i have used `tabBarPosition: 'bottom',` to display tabs bottom of the screen. Can you show me how to navigate between views, which includes the tabbarpanel as well. The following code is my Main.js, and this is where i have included tabs.

```
Ext.define("app.view.Main", {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',


    config: {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

        items: [
            {
                xtype:'formReq'

            }
        ]
    }

});
```

Comment: Actually, you did use a tabpanel (tabpanel is the alias or xtype for Ext.tab.Panel). And it seems you added what I guess is a formpanel to it. Again, I am guessing that from a button on this form you execute your Ajax request. The thing is, if you want to have the two views mentioned above as tabs in your tabpanel, just add them to it and navigate the way I explained. If you don't want to have those views as tabs, then use Ext.Viewport (and navigation), but it is then normal that you don't see the tabbar when you navigate to those views, since they are fullscreen views.

Comment: Is there anyway i could modify my code, to make it a Navigation based application (as in Native iOS development)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very precise.
Nevertheless, if you are asking how to navigate between pages, it all depends how they are set up.
Assuming you added your two views (RegistrationView and InformationView) to the app viewport (Ext.ViewPort):

```
Ext.Viewport.add(MyApp.view.RegistrationView)
Ext.Viewport.add(MyApp.view.InformationView)
```

then all you have to do is the following:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: 'http://call.com/the_webservice',
                    params : values,

                    failure: function (response) {
                    var text = response.responseText;
                    Ext.ViewPort.setActiveItem(0);

                    },                              
                    success: function (response) {

                    var text = response.responseText;
                    Ext.ViewPort.setActiveItem(1);
});
```

This is just one way of doing it (maybe not the best).
hope this helps.

Comment: Where should i add the `Viewport` code in my application ? in the app.js ? Is it in the `launch` function ? (I am a beginner)

Comment: Yes, i did as you suggested, but it doesn't navigate. I have updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: So you added two views to Ext.ViewPort numbered 0 and 1. If you want to navigate to app.view.Register, you have to navigate to view 1: Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(1).

Comment: Yes, it works. But i don't see the `TabBar Controller` below the view. How do i get that ?

Comment: Again, you're not really precise... If you are talking about a tabPanel that you have, then instead of adding your views to Ext.Viewport, you add them to your tabPanel, and you proceed in the same way to navigate: myTabPanel.setActiveItem(...).

Comment: I have updated my question above. I have included my 'Main.js' file. How should i write the code to navigate views which includes the TabBar bottom of the screen ?